# strlen is showing 0 for two byte string

Tags: c, memcpy

I am trying to use strlen to print the length of the string. I know its 2 bytes in length. However, strlen returns zero. Could someone please explain me why? Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int16_t f = -105;
    unsigned char *s = malloc(2+1);
    uint16_t m = htons((uint16_t)f);
    memcpy(s,(unsigned char*)&m, 2);
    int16_t v = s[0] << 8 | s[1];
    printf("%i \n",m);
    printf("%i \n",v);
    printf("%zu \n", strlen(s));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: print the string `s` itself to see what happens.

Comment: `m ` is not a sting an coping its value to a  `char * ` does not make it a string...

Comment: i don't understand a string in C, is a array of char end by '\0'. You try to reverse byte order of a int16_t and stock it in a string ? No cense. What is your purpose ? We could help you a lot more.

Comment: I have to send a signed 16 bit integer with same two bytes in UDP packet. What I was trying to do is use htons to use 2bytes and put in string so I can add all values to end of string and send it.

Comment: you want to send a series of bytes, not a string

Comment: yes, i have values like 100, -25,-35, -22, 25, I used htons to make it bystes and write into string. I am not sure its right way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a uint16_t to a file descriptor

```
int socket;
...
uint16_t m = htons(-105);
write(socket, &m, sizeof(m));
```

No need to use a string or a buffer here.

If you need to write more than one value you can use a buffer. A little example.

```
struct buffer {
    uintmax_t size;
    uint8_t buffer[1024];
}

bool    add_uint16_t(struct buffer *buffer, uint16_t value)
{
    if (buffer->size + 2 >= 1024)
        return true;
    buffer->buffer[buffer->size++] = (value >> 0u) & 0xFFu;
    buffer->buffer[buffer->size++] = (value >> 8u) & 0xFFu;
    return false;
}

bool write_buffer(struct buffer *buffer, int socket)
{
    return write(socket, buffer->buffer, buffer->size) != buffer->size;
}

void reset_buffer(struct buffer *buffer)
{
    buffer->size = 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to add more values to one packet. more than 100 16 bit values. Thats why I was using string.

Comment: use a buffer if you want like a char buffer[1024], forget the string. But if you need to buffering, it's very hard to do. You need it for a specific project ? What is you protocol ? I can make you a little example, wait.

Comment: UDP, I use sendto in that "const void *message"

Comment: when i talk about protocol i talk something like [that](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7049). If I understand you use a home made protocol :p. I write you a little example that hold 512 values of 2 bytes.

Comment: To avoid endianness better to serialize data: `buffer->buffer[buffer->size++] = (value >> 0u) & 0xFFu; buffer->buffer[buffer->size++] = (value >> 8u) & 0xFFu;`

Answer (score 0):

You copied a part of a number into the array

```
memcpy(s,(unsigned char*)&m, 2);
```

It can occur such a way that as result the first byte of the array will be equal to 0 and strlen will return also 0.

The function `strlen` counts bytes until a zero byte will encountered.